# QgsMapToolEmitPoint.canvasReleaseEvent not firing with SHIFT modifier

Tags: qgis, qgis-plugins, qgis-2, pyqt, event-listener

I've created a plugin that implements a Map Tool. It captures mouse click events, which works fine. Now  I want to capture Shift+Mouseclick. This doesn't work at all, while Alt+Mouseclick and Ctrl+Mouseclick do work. What's causing this?

The way I'm capturing the events is as follows:

```
class GeometryTool(QgsMapToolEmitPoint):
    def canvasReleaseEvent(self, event):
        QgsMessageLog.logMessage("Click: " + str(event.button()))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For documentation purposes I'll answer my own question. Not sure if I'm supposed to.
I had to resort to the source code to find this out.

QgsMapToolEmitPoint inherits from QgsMapTool. All it really adds, is a two line function creating a canvasClicked event that returns an xy-point. That AND overriding the Flags method so that it returns the QgsMapTool.AllowZoomRect flag. This basically tells QGis to attach a sort of secondary zoom function to the tool:

> Allow zooming by rectangle (by holding shift and dragging) while the tool is active.
>   This interferes with the capturing of Shift-Click events.

I was using QgsMapToolEmitPoint because the sample in the [QGis Cookbook](https://docs.qgis.org/2.18/en/docs/pyqgis_developer_cookbook/canvas.html#writing-custom-map-tools) does this, even though the added functionality of this class is never used in the example.

So, to cut a long story short: Use [QgsMapTool](https://qgis.org/api/2.18/classQgsMapTool.html) for your map tools (adding the canvasCicked event yourself if you really need it).